# How to compare the Values in two different columns if the Values are same get the values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Column B has Values of customer Number (multiple times) till Row 1000 and column A has the sales orders information like below.

```
Column  A       Column B 
ORDER1          KRISHNA
ORDER2          RAVI
ORDER3          KRISHNA
```

Now in Column C I Have again customer name and Column D, E Contains E mail id and the Ph No of customer. So It will be like

```
Column  A       Column B    Column C    Column D            Column E
ORDER1          KRISHNA     KRISHNA     Krihsna@gmail       12345
ORDER2          RAVI        RAVI        Ravi@yahoo          23456 
ORDER3          KRISHNA
```

Now  I want to insert two more columns in between B and C, would like to see the Value of E mail id and Phone number against to the customers for the column B .

Out Put should look like .

```
Column  A       Column B       Column c            Column D
ORDER1          KRISHNA        Krihsna@gmail       12345
ORDER2          RAVI           Ravi@yahoo          23456 
ORDER3          KRISHNA        Krihsna@gmail       12345
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the final output you expect after inserting the 2 extra columns.

Comment: If contents in column C D & E are not duplicates and it kind of holds the master info about name, mail id & phone, you can simply use VLOOKUP function against column B to pull the info from this master table.

Answer (score 0):

Use one `VLOOKUP` formula for each eMail address and phone number, like this (after inserting blank columns C and D, the "database" is in columns E, F, G):
in C1, insert `=VLOOKUP($B1,$E:$G,2,FALSE)`
in D1, insert `=VLOOKUP($B1,$E:$G,3,FALSE)`

For efficiency, after filling in all customer data (name, mail address, phone number) in columns E to G, select the filled-in range and name it (Ctrl-F3). Use that name (e.g. `customers`) instead of `$E:$G` in the above formulas.